# C++ ABI: personality routine in 'operator delete'?

Tags: c++, g++, clang, llvm, abi

Let's consider this program:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// void operator delete(void* p, int i)
template <class T> void operator delete(void* p, T i)
{
  printf("Success\n");
}

template <class T> void* operator new(size_t s, T i)
{
  return new char[s];
}

struct A {
  A() {throw 42;}
};

int main()
{
  try {
    new (1234) A;
  }
  catch (int i) { 
    printf("Inside catch block\n");
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

When generating an assembly code with clang++, the `operator delete` contains personality routine

```
  .section  .text._ZdlIiEvPvT_,"axG",@progbits,_ZdlIiEvPvT_,comdat
  .weak _ZdlIiEvPvT_            # -- Begin function _ZdlIiEvPvT_
  .p2align  4, 0x90
  .type _ZdlIiEvPvT_,@function
_ZdlIiEvPvT_:                           # @_ZdlIiEvPvT_
.Lfunc_begin1:
  .cfi_startproc
  **.cfi_personality 155, DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0**
  .cfi_lsda 27, .Lexception1
# %bb.0:
...
```

When generating with g++, it does not.

What's the reason to have personality routine in `operator delete`?
What's the difference between clang and gcc in this regard?

My environment:
OS: Ubuntu 21.04
g++ (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2) 11.2.0
clang version 10.0.1

Comment: Don't *all* functions that can catch exceptions need a personality routine?

Comment: Yes. How is that the case for this `operator delete` ?

Comment: Generally speaking, LLVM encourages compilers to generate code simply, and let LLVM passes do any necessary cleanup instead of trying to generate optimal IR in the beginning. In this concrete case, the simplest way to use LLVM encourages generating a Function object (including personality and attributes) before looking at the implementation, which implies that you do it without even trying to check whether the function's implementation *really* requires the personality and each attribute.

Comment: What I understand from your last comment is that it might generate personality for all functions in IR and then passes will remove them by looking into the implementation. Right? Why does `operator new` have no personality, because some pass has removed it?

Comment: There is no `operator delete` in assembly with -O3 in this particular case. It vanished it away. But I think this is a very simple case it could optimize.